# Remove selection highlight in listviewgroup?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, listview

This is what happens when you hover your mouse over one of my listview groups: http://localhostr.com/file/930/vtdFrMNdvDwz/Untitled.png

I researched on the msdn website for System::Windows::Forms::ListViewGroup and came up with no results relating to how to disable selection of a group / the click event as well.

The listview and groups are made with the designer in visual studio 2010 vc++ windows form and automatically generate this code:

```
System::Windows::Forms::ListViewGroup^  listViewGroup5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ListViewGroup(L"Player", System::Windows::Forms::HorizontalAlignment::Center));
```

I am currently using the following code to override WndProc for my form and I assume that the answer to my solution would be to also override WndProc for listview and if that is the case, how would I combine it into 1 piece of code...and if not, what would be the solution?

```
protected:
    virtual void WndProc(Message% m) override 
    {
        __super::WndProc(m);
        if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST) 
        {
            switch ((int)m.Result) 
            {
            case HTLEFT: 
            case HTRIGHT: 
            case HTTOP: 
            case HTTOPLEFT: 
            case HTTOPRIGHT:
            case HTBOTTOMLEFT: 
            case HTBOTTOMRIGHT:
                m.Result = (IntPtr)HTCLIENT;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express) and [Better ListView](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview) controls have this already implemented. Simply call:

```
betterListView.GroupHeaderBehavior = betterListView.GroupHeaderBehavior & ~BetterListViewGroupHeaderBehavior.MouseHighlight;
```

to turn off group header highlighting.

There are also other group header options: mouse focus, keyboard focus and group selection.

Comment: BetterListView does NOT work in C++/CLI, I just experienced many errors and customer support did say infact it is a problem on their side!

Comment: It is a problem introduced by a Babel.NET obfuscator, there is little we can do about it. We use about a dozen of 3rd party tools.
Please note Microsoft does not recommend C++/CLI for UI development anyway; they even dropped Windows Forms Application Template from Visual Studio 2012. You can still use Better ListView via a class library written in any CLI language (C#, VB.NET, F# ...).